# How to stop function after next() in node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

Ok, I have code like this:

```
app.get('/someUrl', function(req, res, next){
    if(req.body.username==''){
        next({'type':'error', 'httpCode':400, 'message': {'errCode': 'e402', 'text': 'Not name specified'}})
    }

    var user=new User({'name':'Jack Leeeee'})
    user.save(function(err, affected) {
        if (err) next({'type': 'error', 'httpCode': 400, 'message': {'errCode': 'e403', 'text': 'Bad error :('}})
        console.log('all is ok!')
        res.send(200, "Ok")
    })
})
```

When I try to send empty request, my error handler send to me right response by next() function. But after this user schema trying to save(that makes exception). How I can stop app.get() function after calling next()?

Only way, that I found is call

```
return false;
```

after next(), but this method didn't work in async functions(like user.save()), it's obviously

UPD1: In another word, how to avoid 'Still alive' in console?

```
user.save(function(err,c){
    return next(err)
})
console.log('Still alive')
```

Comment: The usual pattern I've seen is `if (err) return next(err);` at the very top of the function. So your instinct to return is correct. Can you explain more why that method doesn't work for you?

Comment: In async functions you can return only from callback, that in fact is another function and don't know about function that call it: user.save(function(err,c){ return next(err)}) returns from anonymous function

Comment: `return` will stop all code after it from executing within the function. Meaning neither `console.log` or `res.send` will run.

Comment: You're not actually trying to return a value. It's just the easiest way to halt execution. It's roughly the same as doing `if (err){ next(err); } else { /** other code **/ }` just a bit nicer.

Answer (score 7):

Either you want node+express's asynchronous `next()` behaviour, or you need to cut it off explicitly:

```
var middleware = {
  auth: function(req, res, next) {
    if(req.body.username=='') {
     return next({
       'type':'error',
       'httpCode':400,
       'message': {
         'errCode': 'e402',
         'text': 'Not name specified'
       }
     });
    }
    next();
  }
}

var routes = {
  someurl: function(req, res) {
    console.log('all is ok!')
    res.send(200, "Ok")
  }
}

app.use(function universalErrorHandler(req, res, next, err) {
  console.error("oh no something went wrong!");
  console.error(err);
});


app.get('/someUrl', middleware.auth, routes.someurl);
```

The idea is you do every "step" in its own function. Should processing continue? call next() without an error argument. Should processing be aborted? call next() with an error argument. When express sees a `next(err)` being called, it'll send it over to the global error handler if there is one, or throw an exception if you didn't define one.

Notice that your code has been split up into three parts: a middleware object for handling "in the middle" checks, a routing object for generating the final data that should come back from URL requests, and an `app.get` for a route that has one middleware step, and one final content generating function.

The idea with express is to do as little as possible per step. Need to verify four parameters? That's four middleware functions, and then called as `app.get("someroute", fn1, fn2, fn3, fn4, generatePage)`, with each middleware function either calling `next()` on success, or `next(new Error(...});` when something went wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Like it was said in the comments

```
return next(err)
```

should solve your problems.